# Mongoose Populate Cache

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have many different mongoose schemas referencing each other by id strings.

I'm using redis to cache mongoose documents.

For instance, getUser(id) will return a previously cached user object if exists, otherwise it'll call mongoose find.

It'd feel more aesthetic to instead have mongoose references and use populate.

However, from what I understand, it's just syntactic sugar for find and doesn't have any caching layer.

**Main Question**

When should mongoose populate be used vs a caching layer, and what're the best practices in stable high traffic apps using mongoose?

**Guiding Sub-Questions**

1. Is mongoose populate really fit for high traffic apps?
2. Is there any benefit to using populate over caching documents
   myself?
3. Is caching models myself (e.g. using redis) negligible performance-wise?
4. What's the best practice? What do big app companies that use
   mongoose do?
5. Would you mix populating mongoose references and a caching layer
   depending on different use cases or would you choose one and be
   consistent with it?

**Example Use Case**

Here's a common plain example from my app.

I have 3 collections: User, App, Institute.

1. User has a ref to App
2. App has a ref to Institute

Right now I'm:

1. Fetching User from caching layer, which contains an app_id
2. Fetching app from caching layer, which contains institute_id
3. Fetching institute from the caching layer

Given a user, fetching app and institute from the caching layer is practically O(1).

However, if I choose to do pure mongoose populate, it'll take 2 extra find calls to the database - for app, and then for institute.

I need the user with app and institute populated on each authenticated request to the server.

Of course there are more complex use cases, but this is the most common one.

My simplest requests require populating 4 references on average, while the more complex ones can get to populating many more.

Comment: depends how You "cook" Your models :) In my experience I could insert 100 000 documents per second to mongodb, but I admit that server was with 32 gigs of ram and 8 threads (4 cores). Also depending on business logic You can make `_id` customized (string) which can help with getting document by id instead of query-in by conditions. (ex.: `users collection:  _id = "someusername"` to not to create index on `username` field)

Comment: if You want best practices, better share Your models (schemas) and use cases. That will help SO members to give best solutions.

Comment: Sounds like quite a lot, but it's indeed a strong machine.

In your case, are you using populate?

In my business logic I'm actually comfortable with the plain old auto generated ids.

I added a simple use case in the original question.

Comment: All depends on use case. about Your use case: in any case You're doing request to caching layer, so problem comes what if caching layer cannot hold high load? :) also getting document by id is faster than getting document by some field (even if it's indexed).
Complex use cases: I think instead of having caching layer it would be better to have Elastic Search which will react to changes and make ready to use search indexes that will hold necessary data.
I use message bus (event buss) and react to changes by collecting and storing datasets which holds all relational data together in CouchBase

Comment: in any case doing extra query to db or doing 2nd query to cache is not a big deal if it's about getting documents by _id. Think about opening some file which name is like _id in some folder.
But for complex use cases use ElasticSearch or do Your own workers which will prefetch data and put somewhere separate to speed up access.
P.S. don't forget to put proper indexes to gain lookup speed (may cost extra storage space)

Comment: Got it thanks for the info. Especially this part hit the nail on the head for me: "in any case doing extra ... is like _id in some folder."

I will of course make sure to put proper indexes, and I'm mostly getting documents by _id.

So for such a simple use case for instance, do you think a big app company would go with populate? It seems like that's the direction you're implying, but I'm trying to get you to actually say the words :)

Also, is there any reason you suggested ElasticSearch over Redis or is it just personal preference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my understanding of some of the pros and cons of the twos.

Pros for populate of mongoose

- No additional setup for cache (simpler infrastructure)
- It can Deep populate (populate in multiple levels)
- It can Populate from multiple databases.
- It is a simple clean syntax
- No synchronization required between caching and database because it is a "single" source of truth.

Cons for populate of mongoose

- The database is working for every populate and query instead of your server or a caching layer. If there is a lot of writing on the same instance this will affect the performance of some write if the index needs to be recomputed or a processor-intensive query is made.
- Rely on the inner working of mongoose and of a MongoDB database.
- Needs control because Deep populate can get out of hand with multiple levels.

Pros for caching layer

- Can be multiple levels of cache.  Some per server and a global caching.
- Use the specific force of a caching engine.
- Offload some work to the cache and potentially to the database.

Cons for caching layer

- Need to sync state between the cache and the database
- More infrastructure.
- More code (if you want a clean abstraction)

Overall to answer your subquestions,
1. Populate may be useful in some hight traffic app for something that can't be cache and needs to be live or that is done not really often.

2. Using populate over caching is simpler, less infra, less code, no synchronization.
3. In my experience, I would go for caching because it will be quicker on a big database.  When scaling the database tends to require more cpu and cost more money. Caching on the other hands is cheaper and scales wells.  Also, it is possible to cache per instance. i.e. My server has a local cache before hitting the remote cache.  This makes the performance very quick but it may affect the server performance depending on the hosting.
4. I am not in a big company but our product requires transactional information and a fixed state.  Populate could be used for this case because the database is the only source of truth and we don't want to have an incorrect state.  Due to the replication of our database, it is not a single source but at least we would be close to the database.  Everywhere else we use caching.  We have multiple databases and multiple databases type and caching gives us more performance.  Our micro-service oriented architecture also benefits a lot from caching and ensures that the data is not all in the same database but is still fast to access.
5. Yes, mixing is a good option depending on the use case.  A general tip will be to understand the potential hot spot and to try to spread the workload around to ensure one part of the infrastructure is not the bottleneck.

Final tip: In doubt make sure to keep code interface between the data layer and the code layer.  This abstraction is very useful if ElasticSearch needs to be used instead of Redis or any other caching service.  Code interface will postpone the need to make a commitment.

Example: Instead of using `App.populate` directly in a piece of code adding a method `getFullApp()` in your schema that calls `this.populate()`

```
const AppSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...});

AppSchema.static({
   getFullApp(query) {
      return this.find(query).populate()
   }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("App", AppSchema);
```

If you want to get rid of the populate there is only one place to change it or get rid of mongoose `getFullApp` is function of your code interface.